# heroku api call from nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

Is there a nodejs module to call heroku api?

I tried this: node-heroku

It works:

```
heroku = require("heroku");
client = new heroku.Heroku({key: "deadbeef"});
client.get_releases("my_app", function (error, result) {});
```

But I cant get working: post_key, put_app...
Is there any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Heroku-API wrapper for node.js on GitHub](https://github.com/avdgaag/heroku-api). It looks like the documentation is down, so you'll have to spelunk the code.